# how to insert vector only once in multiple thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have below code snippet.

```
std::vector<int> g_vec;

void func()
{
    //I add double check to avoid thread need lock every time.
    if(g_vec.empty())
    {
       //lock
       if(g_vec.empty())
       {
          //insert items into g_vec
       }
       //unlock
    }

    ...
}
```

`func` will be called by multiple thread, and I want `g_vec` will be inserted items only once which is a bit similar as `singleton instance`. And about `singleton instance`, I found there is a [`DCLP`](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-and-the-perils-of-double-checked-locki/184405726) issue.

**Question**:
1. My above code snippet is thread safe, is it has DCLP issue?
2. If not thread safe, how to modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a data race.

The first check outside the lock is not synchronized with the insertion inside the lock. That means, you may end up with one thread reading the vector (through `.empty()`) while another thread is writing the vector (through `.insert()`), which is [by definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) a data race and leads to undefined behavior.

A solution for exactly this kind of problem is given by the standard in form of [`call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once).

```
#include<mutex>

std::vector<int> g_vec;
std::once_flag g_flag;

void func()
{
    std::call_once(g_flag, [&g_vec](){ g_vec.insert( ... ); });
}
```

Comment: if not use c++11, how to fix it?

Comment: @JerryYYRain Boost provides [an implementation of call_once](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.once) as well. Also your system's API may have a [similar mechanism](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_once.html) available.

Answer (score -1):

In your example, it could happen that second reentrant thread will find a non empty half initialized vector, that it's something that you won`t want anyway. You should use a flag, and mark it when initialization job is completed. Better a standard one, but a simple static int will do the job as well

```
std::vector<int> g_vec;

void func()
{
    //I add double check to avoid thread need lock every time.
    static int called = 0;
    if(!called)
    {
       lock()
       if(!called)
       {
          //insert items into g_vec
          called = 1;
       }
       unlock()
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Now you have a data race on the `int`. A `static int` is *not* sufficient here, due to the lack of guarantees regarding atomicity and memory ordering.